# Convergence of a sequence $g_n(x)$ to $g(x) = 1-|x|$ in $W^{1,p}(B(0,r=1) \setminus 0)$ for $1 \le p \le 2$ , where $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, sobolev-spaces

Consider the sequence $\{g_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by

> $$g_n(x) =\max \left\{ 0, \min \left\{1-\frac{n+1}{n}\Vert x\Vert, n- \ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\Vert x\Vert}\right) \right\}   \right\}.$$

How can I prove that $\{g_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to

> $$g(x)= 1-\Vert x \Vert$$

in $W^{1,p}(B(0,r=1) \setminus 0)$, where $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, for $$1 \le p \le 2$$ as $n \to \infty$?

> That is, how can I prove that 
>   $$\int_{-1}^{1} |g_n(x)-g(x)|^p  \ \mathrm{d}x \to 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad \int_{-1}^{1} |\nabla g_n(x)-\nabla g(x)|^p  \ \mathrm{d}x \to 0$$
>   for $$1 \le p \le 2$$ as $n \to \infty$?

---

---

The one-dimensional case was solved by an answer given by @Dap. The following pictures refer to that case.

[This is the plot of $g$ produced by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1-Abs%5Bx%5D,%20%7Bx,%20-1,%201%7D%5D):

[image]

For $n=2$, [this is the plot of $g_n$ produced by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BMax%5B0,Min%5B1%20-%20(3%20Abs%5Bx%5D)%2F2,%202%20-%20Log%5BLog%5B(1%20%2B%20Abs%5Bx%5D%5E(-1))%20%5D%5D%5D%5D,%20%7Bx,%20-1,%201%7D%5D):
[image]

My main difficulties are in estimating the integrals for $|x| \le |\tilde{x}|$, where $|\tilde{x}|$ is the value of $x$ where the maximum is achieved.

Comment: Do you have any ideas, or experience with showing that a sequence converges in this Sobolev space? What this question is lacking (compared with the rather "high" level of Mathematics it is about) is some effort from you, OP.

Comment: @mickep, yes; I just have a very concrete problem in estimating the integrals. I cannot even get started for small |x|.

Comment: @mickep I edited the question anyway.

Comment: Maybe try the dominated convergence theorem for the 1st integral?

Answer (score 1):

If a function $f$ is continuous, differentiable and monotone on an interval $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b|\partial_xf|=|\int_a^b\partial_xf|=|f(b)-f(a)|.$

We can break up these functions into monotone pieces. $\int_{-1}^1|\partial_xg|=\int_{-1}^0|\partial_xg|+\int_{0}^1|\partial_xg|=2.$

Let $x^*$ be the value maximizing $g(x^*)$ subject to $x^*\in[0,1].$  Integrating $|\partial_xf|$ on the four intervals gives $\int_{-1}^1 |\partial_xg_n|=\int_{-1}^{-x^*} |\partial_xg_n|+\int_{-x^*}^0 |\partial_xg_n|+\int_{0}^{x^*} |\partial_xg_n|+\int_{x^*}^1 |\partial_xg_n|=4g_n(x^*)\approx 4.$

We have shown $\|\partial_x g_n\|_1\approx 4$ and $\|\partial_x g\|_1=2.$ So $\partial_x g_n$ does not converge to $\partial_x g$ in $L^1([-1,1]\setminus\{0\}).$ On a finite domain, $L^p$ convergence is a stronger requirement so they don't converge for $p>1$ either.

More generally, functions in $W^{1,1}$ have an (absolutely) continuous representative, and a sequence of functions $f_n$ with $f_n(0)=0$ cannot converge to a function with $f_n(0)=1$ in $W^{1,1}(0,1)$, or even in [$BV$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation).

Comment: Where did you get those numbers?

Comment: @Rene: I've added more detail. The $\|\partial_x g_n\|_1=4$ should have been a $\approx.$

Comment: I see. Does the answer change if we consider the ball $B(0,r=1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @Rene: it might do - I don't know off-hand

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to include your answer.